# Htaccess rewriting rule for localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wampserver

The project is already running in prod, the developer who added that rule is no longer working with us but it is pretty working in prod, so in order to have the project working locally I tried many options, now I set the SSL in my web server and set virtual host to match exactly the prod so that it can run correctly, in the code the sign form is sent by session but it is blocked for security reason and I am pretty sure that it is related to htaccess and here are the full rules mentioned in htaccess:  # -- SITE PAGES ---

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?_htaccess_url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule https://www.sanatariol.com(.+)\.html$ index.php?_htaccess_url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

The URL of sign page is:  https://www.sanitavia.com/cabchatt/connexion.html

Do I have to add a rule in htacces since I want it to run locally?

Comment: You don't need a rule for that, just add your domain in `/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`. Add to your `hosts` file `sanatoariol.com` and `www.sanatariol.com`, both on `127.0.0.1`, a setup for the virtual hosts might be required afterwards, depending on your documentRoot. But remember, you cannot access it publicly anymore because it will bind to your local machine. FYI `www.sanatariol.com` and `sanatariol.com` are two different domains.

Comment: yes, that's what I did already, it was working until I added the rule in htaccess file so I thought that I didn't type it correctly, is there any error on my rule?

Comment: You don't actually state what it is you are trying to do and what URLs you are requesting. (You only give the code that is "not working" - but without saying what it is supposed to be doing?)

Comment: does your URL path is simply localhost ? or does it have a path like localhost/websites/my-project ? If it's the latter, then you must set in htaccess the `RewriteBase` to your relative path to make it accesible.

Comment: yes it is like localhost/websites/my-project

Comment: You don't _need_ to set `RewriteBase` unless `index.php` is in a different directory to the `.htaccess` file. @darklightcode

Comment: hello yes index.php is in a different directory

Comment: "it is like localhost/websites/my-project" - So, you're not actually requesting your required domain? And these URLs don't end in `.html`? You need to state in natural language what it is you are trying to do, as this URL doesn't appear to have anything to do with the directive you have in your question? If "index.php is in a different directory" then you need to describe your folder structure.

Comment: @MrWhite it looks like it's in a different directory, that's why i asked. Indeed, if the project was in the webserver root there was no need for RewriteBase. Thus OP can access the project by full path, or if he wants the location to be loaded only from the domain name he must set a virtual host also with a different DocumentRoot.

Comment: thanks for your help, I edited the question to make everything clearer

Comment: I edited the question because I didn't  ask the question properly, I am sorry.

Comment: _“but it is blocked for security reason and I am pretty sure that it is related to htaccess”_ - that’s still not what could actually be called a good problem description. We don’t know what “blocked for security reason” actually means, so we don’t know if it is even actually related to the .htaccess / URL rewriting either - currently, we can only take your word for that; and seeing how your expertise and knowledge on the topic doesn’t seem to be particularly outstanding to begin with, that is rather little. This is _still_ in need of a proper problem description in the first place.

Comment: As mentioned above, despite your edit, you've still not stated what the _specific_ problem is (with enough detail to identify a solution). If the project is already "running in prod" and you've configured a local development server "to match exactly the prod" then you wouldn't necessarily expect to have to change or add anything to `.htaccess` for this to work locally. The directive you posted initially (now the second directive), that references the domain name, isn't doing anything (as mentioned in my answer) - even on the "prod" server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rule is correct but try to add this just before your rule

```
    RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule https://www.sanatariol.com(.+)\.html$ index.php?_htaccess_url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` directive matches against the URL-path only (not the absolute URL). So, the above rule will not match.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ index.php?_htaccess_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You also don't need to manually append the query string, use the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag instead.

Comment: hello thanks for your response I did try it but same as before

Comment: Please explain what it is you are trying to do. All you've done is present some code that is "not working", without actually saying what it is you are trying to do?!